# Increasing sequence of permutation of an arithmetic progression

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a permutation of the set $\mathbb{N}$ of all positive integers. Show that there must be an arithmetic progression $a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d$ where $d>0$ such that $\sigma(a)<\sigma(a+d)<\sigma(a+2d)<\sigma(a+3d)$?

I could prove that $\sigma(a)<\sigma(a+d)<\sigma(a+2d)$ but I couldn't prove further.

Comment: Do you try ab absurdo ?

Comment: Maybe you can expand a bit on how you proved this for 3 elements instead of 4?

Comment: @EDX did you mean contradicting by taking $\sigma(a+2d)>\sigma(a+3d)$. If yes, then I have tried.